# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable at last lne

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am receiving the TypeError: 'int' object is not callable at last Line "print(max(lenght1)):

Please suggest

```
l=[int(x) for x in "10,22,9,33,21,50,41,60,80".split(sep = ",")]
print(l)
length1 = [1 for i in range(len(l))]
for i in range(len(l)):
    max = l[i]
    for j in range(i+1,len(l)):
        if l[j]>max:
            max=l[j]
            length1[i]=length1[i]+1
print(max(length1))
```

Comment: This happens because you you used `max` as a variable name, which shadowed the built-in `max` function. It's preferable to not use built-in names of functions, types etc. as variable names.

Comment: Thanks @sammy u saved me a day. This things always irritate in python.

Comment: Well, everything in Python is an object, be it a function or a type (class), built-in or user-defined. And objects have names. So, if you re-bind the name, it references a different object. Once you get used to this concept, everything else seems totally unintuitive ;)

Comment: @AlokKumar If you are using an editor with syntax highlighting, just rename your variable if the editor highlights the variable as if it were a function. In your case, it probably would have highlighted `max`. Or, use a static analysis tool like `flake8` or `pylint` to warn you of things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you used `max` as a variable name, which shadowed the built-in `max` function. It's preferable to not use built-in names of functions, types etc. as variable names.